# Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure of Singletons - when is it zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing, right-continuous and nonnegative.  Define the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_f$ by
$$
\mu_f(a,b] = f(b) - f(a).
$$

> When does $\mu_f\{b\} = 0$?

I think it is true for linear such $f$, since $f(0) = 0$.  Proof:  Let $f$ be linear and let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then
$$
\mu_f\{b\} \leq \mu_f(b-\epsilon, b] = f(b) - f(b - \epsilon) = f(\epsilon).
$$
Since this holds $\forall \epsilon > 0$,
$$
\mu\{b\} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \mu_f\{b\} \leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} f(\epsilon) = f(0) = 0,
$$
where I used right-continuity of $f$ in the second-to-last equality and linearity of $f$ for the last.

> Hence $\mu_f\{b\} = 0$ for linear such $f$

It looks like it's also true for affine such $f$.  Is there a more general result?

**Update** Thanks to Cain's comment, we also get $\mu_f\{b\} = 0$ for continuous such $f$.

Comment: If you'll inspect your claim you will notice you've only used the fact that a linear function is continous. Try to generalize this idea.

Comment: @Cain Ah, good eye.  I see it.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: even more, notice that you just need right continuity.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi hmm, okay.  Since every Lebesgue-Stieltjes function is right-continuous, we get $\mu_f\{b\} = 0$ for any such $f$??  I seemed to have thought it was possible that $\mu_f\{b\} > 0$ for some $f$.

Comment: Is true for any measurable function in this class.

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi is mistaken here.  Points can have positive measure even when $f$ is right continuous; consider $f = 1_{[0,\infty)}$ which is a point mass at 0.  They will have zero measure iff $f$ is also *left* continuous.  Measurability is not relevant; indeed, every Lebesgue-Stieltjes function is measurable.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I didnt even remeber this comment. Thanks foir pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully someone finds this later answer useful. What is actually true (see exercise 1.28 in Folland's *Real Analysis*) is that $$\mu_F(\{a\})=F(a)-F(a-),$$ where $F$ is increasing and right-continuous. It need not, of course, be true for such $F$ that $F(a-)=F(a)$. Consider
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}~x<1\\
1&\text{if}~x\geq 1
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $F$ is increasing and right continuous, but $$\mu_F(\{1\})=F(1)-F(1-)=F(1)-\lim_{x\nearrow 1}F(x)=1-0=1>0.$$