# Integration with respect to measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(\Omega),\lambda)$, some Borel measure $\mu:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to[0,\infty]$ and a Lebesgue measurable function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, und what conditions is it possible to calculate
$$\int_\Omega f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=\int_\Omega f(x)\mu(x)\mathrm{d}x\ ?$$

Can you give me some reference on where I can find a result like this (perhaps in a more general setting)? I have the feeling that many authors implicitly use this "transformation", but I would like to see a rigorous proof of it.

Comment: $\mu$ takes a measurable set as argument, i.e. for $x\in\Omega$ the expression $\mu(x)$ on the right hand side is not defined.

Comment: The singleton set $\{x\}\subset\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases $\mu(\{x\})$ will be zero, since Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441457/lebesgue-stieltjes-measure-of-singletons-when-is-it-zero) post explores this case.

Therefore I suppose that $\mu(x)$ probably does not mean $\mu(\{x\})$, but rather the density of $\mu$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. To avoid confusion, denote $g$ as this density, i.e. a measurable nonnegative function such that $\mu = g\ d\lambda$. If $f$ is also nonnegative and measurable, i.e. a density w.r.t. $\mu$, then we will have
$$ \int f(x)\ d\mu(x) = \int f(x)\cdot g(x)\ d\lambda(x) $$

This can be proven by letting $f=\chi_A$ for $A\in\mathcal{B}$, then using linearity to show this for simple functions. The monotone convergence theorem yields this result for nonnegative measurable $f$.

Note that if actually $\mu(x)=\mu(\{x\})$ you would be suggesting that all measures $\nu = f\ d\mu$  are absolutely continuous to the Lebesgue measure with this very specific density $f\cdot \mu(\{\cdot\})$.

Comment: First let me thank you for your answer. You write $\mu=g~d\lambda$, how do I interpret this relation? Is it equivalent to the (for me more) common relation $d\mu=g~d\lambda$, i.e. $\int_Ad\mu=\int_Ag~d\lambda$ for all measurable $A$? I am very new to measure theory, therefore I frequently get confused with all these notation.

Comment: Yes, this is what it means. Sorry, I think more common is to either write $d\mu = g d\lambda$ or $\mu = g\cdot \lambda$, @bongobums .