# Integration with respect to Borel measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, examples-counterexamples

Context first: I'm brushing up a little on measure theory, mainly trying to get a better understanding of integration with respect to measures other than the Lebesgue measure.

I came across the following in a research article:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\eta: \mathbb{R}_-\to \mathcal{L}(X)$ be of bounded variation such that $|\eta|(\mathbb{R}_-)<\infty,$ where $|\eta|$ is the positive Borel measure in $\mathbb{R}_-$ defined by the total variation on $\eta$ and $\Phi : C_0(\mathbb{R}_-,X) \cap L^p(\mathbb{R}_-,X) \to X$ be the map $$f \mapsto\int_{-\infty}^0 f \ d\eta.$$

I want to practice computing $\Phi$ for different $f.$ However, due to my lack of knowledge, I am not sure what examples of $\eta$ fit the situation. So what I'm looking for is reference/examples of such $\eta$ (the simpler the better). I have no qualms about sticking to the particular case $X = \mathbb{C}$ for simplicity since I just want to work on computing $\Phi$ in concrete cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you stick to $X=\mathbb C$ if you want to compute anything explicitly.

Here are some cases you should try:

- $\eta$ is a continuous function
- $\eta$ is a simple function

Comment: As I understand from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3623105/266110), $\Phi(f)= \int f \ g \ d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $g$ is the density. How do I find $g?$

Comment: $g$ is your $\eta$. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah, so if $\eta= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{A_i},$ then $\Phi(f)= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \int_{A_i \cap \mathbb{R}_-}f(x) dx?$ When I take $\eta$ to be continuous function, it needs to be bounded on $\mathbb{R}_-,$ so that $|\eta|(\mathbb{R}_-) <\infty?$

Comment: Yes, and yes. $ $